# Celery: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply_async'

Tags: python, celery

I get an error `'function' object has no attribute 'apply_async'` when trying to run a celery task

**db_sinc.py**

```
def create_or_update_google_creative():
    ...logic
```

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def run_create_or_update_google_creative():
    print('Task running')
    try:
        result = create_or_update_google_creative()
        return 201, {'message': 'Database successfully updated'}
    except Exception as ex:
        return 500, {'message': 'Database query error'}
```

**views.py**

```
def run_db_sinc():
    result = run_create_or_update_google_creative.apply_async()
    print('+++++++++')
    print(result.get(timeout=1))
```

When I run `run_db_sinc` an error occurs. How to fix it?

p/s

After changing the code in accordance with the comment sahasrara62 the fuction is running but in the end I got

```
tuple' object has no attribute 'apply_async'
gpanel_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
gpanel_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 99, in run
gpanel_1  |     result = self.view_func(request, **values)
gpanel_1  |   File "/app/apps/creative_performer/api.py", line 63, in save_creative
gpanel_1  |     return run_db_sinc()
gpanel_1  |   File "/app/apps/creative_performer/views.py", line 136, in run_db_sinc
gpanel_1  |     result = x.apply_async()
gpanel_1  | AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'apply_async'
```

And I can't see result of

```
 print('+++++++++')
    print(result.get(timeout=1))
```

Comment: `x = run_create_or_update_google_creative()  \n
result = x.apply_async()`

Comment: @sahasrara62 script starting running but at the end there is an error. I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

What version of celery using in your project?

Note to [celery doc about "Removals for version 5.0"](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/internals/deprecation.html#id2)

in celery 5 :

```
MyTask.apply_async()          # NO LONGER WORKS


MyTask().apply_async()        # WORKS!
```